# How to return source fields from Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch V7.

I want to fetch only the source fields from Elasticsearch.

**Request query:**

```
GET /test/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "test": {
        "value": "123"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_source" : {
          "field1" : "value1",
          "field2" : "value2",
          "field3" : "value3",
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Expected Result:

```
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
          "field1" : "value1",
          "field2" : "value2",
          "field3" : "value3",
      }, 
      {
          "field1" : "value1",
          "field2" : "value2",
          "field3" : "value3",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

OR

```
    "hits" : [
      {
          "field1" : "value1",
          "field2" : "value2",
          "field3" : "value3",
      }, 
      {
          "field1" : "value1",
          "field2" : "value2",
          "field3" : "value3",
      }
    ]
```

Is there a way to fetch the above expected result from Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. `filter_path` is as good as it gets when it comes to native response filtering.

Having said that, you can use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) -- the command line JSON processor -- to extract the `_sources` further:

```sh
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/test/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source" \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d'{ 
          "query": {   
              "match_all": {} 
          }
        }' \
    | jq '{hits: [.hits.hits[]._source]}'
```